# How to check if an instance is of type enum

Tags: swift

'emun' seems to me like a keyword or a primitive type. 
And obviously following code does not compile:

```
if self is enum {

}
```

But how can I be able to check if certain protocol is implemented by any enum?

```
protocol Enumatable {

} 

extension Enumatable {
    func isEnum() -> Bool {
        return self is enum //it does not compile
    }
}
```

But what I really want is to set some kind of constraint in the protocol to force the adopting class to be an enum. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But the real question is why?

Comment: Well, because using the case structure of an enum I can present a simple and safety api for my library. And I don't want users to be able to implement the protocol with classes or structs, because my library uses the enum's value as an internal key, plus I want that this pattern would be the only way to implement the protocol.

Comment: You may have similar situation as `ErrorType`. The error type is best to used as enum type but this doesn't mean we have to restrict it to enum type. You can't possibly prevent your users shoot themselves in the foot. A good documentation is best you can do.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how performant it is to use Mirrors. But here you go:

```
    enum SomeEnum {
        case one
        case two
    }

    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: SomeEnum.one)
    if let displayStyle = mirror.displayStyle {
        switch displayStyle {
        case .enum:
            print("I am an enum")
        default:
            print("not an enum")
        }
    }
```